# HTML5: Emmet works wrong if I use a smile in my text

Tags: html, emmet

Windows 10, Sublime Text Editor 3, Emmet.

My html file has UTF-8 encoding. I want to insert a smile in the text (I inserted the smile by `Win` + `.` keys pressing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    p{A smile }
</body>
</html>
```

After I wrote `p{A smile }` text I pressed `Tab` key but the string wasn't transformed to html code. Hm... I pressed `Tab` key again and I got the expected result.

Ok... But now I will get the problem in Emmet. I added the text (`ol`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>A smile </p>
    ol>li*5
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if I press the `Tab` key then I get the invalid result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>A smile </p>
    o<ol>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to `o` before `<ol>` tag. Also, `li` item is one, but I expected to get 5 `li` items... I have the problem for some smiles. For example, I get the problem for  smile, but I haven't for ☠.

```
const a = '';
console.log(`a.length: ${a.length}`); // 2
const b = '☠';
console.log(`b.length: ${b.length}`); // 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This seems to rather be a software bug than actually programming-related.

Comment: Hey, if you want to insert Smile in html you can do this via [this w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_smileys.asp)

Comment: @vaku, yes, it solves my problem. Thank you!